# javascript scrollTop loop with new line for "console look"

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I have an array that posts a line to my div called quotes after a duration. Now I want the div to scroll to the bottom with each added line, but I'm having some troubles. I'm using firefox if that changes anything.

```
function showLines(){

    var arr =
    [["Welcome Dave.", 3000],
     ["I'm afraid that I can't do that.", 500],
     ["I wouldn't do that Dave.", 2000],
     ["Now Dave, that wasn't very nice.", 500],
     ["STOP! That Dave!", 1500],
     ["All your base belong to us!", 1000]]
    , i = 0;

    function showLinesHelper()
    {
        document.getElementById("quotes").innerHTML += arr[i++][0]+'<br />';
        if(i < arr.length)
            setTimeout(showLinesHelper, arr[i][1]);
    }

  function Scroll() 
    {
        var objControl=document.getElementById("quotes");
    objControl.scrollTop = objControl.scrollHeight;
    }

    setTimeout(showLinesHelper, arr[0][1], Scroll);            

}
```

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) only takes two arguments: a function and a number. What are the 3 arguments you're passing supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I got it to work... no you can't pass three arguments to setTimeout but you can put the Scroll call inside ShowLinesHelper

http://jsfiddle.net/xDjpx/1